# How can you show Godel's incompleteness theorem using mathematical symbols?

Tags: logic, soft-question

I want to get this as a tattoo as I love the role maths plays in the universe and the idea that the farthest reaches of what we can ever know, fall short of the limits of what is true, even in mathematics. I've done a lot of research but have yet to find a mathematical symbol version of this theorem.

Is there a way to show even a short part of/ the essence of it/ an example of it using symbols?

Sorry if it's inappropriate to ask this here - you just seem like the corner of the internet with my best hope. Any help would be greatly appreciated - I've been trying to find an answer to this for almost a year. Thank you!

Comment: "This tattoo is provably correct if and only if it is incorrect".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A concise version of the first incompleteness theorem might be:

$$\texttt{neither }\;\; \mathbf{PA}\vdash\phi\;\;\texttt{ nor }\;\;\mathbf{PA}\vdash\neg\phi$$

And since I cannot resist, I have to add: but mind, it was the second incompleteness theorem which make the Hilbert Program blew up, not the first.  ; )

PS: If you decide to imprint yourself with Hagen von Eitzen's Formula, I would love to see a picture.

Comment: Thank you! Learning lots today. I can't find a way of finding this out without sounding stupid but what does the PA actually stand for?

Comment: Interesting that you think the second theorem is more relevant. Do you think it's a more accurate representation of, basically, the idea that within any given system, there are claims which are true, but which cannot be proven to be true? If so do you think Yuval's version works... PA⧸⊢Con(PA)

Comment: PS. I wouldn't have been able to get the tattoo without checking on here first so I will share a pic =) Hopefully July!

Comment: It is meant to be the set of the Peano Axioms: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic -- The second incompleteness theorem says that a theory cannot prove its own consistency. Be aware that both theorems state some conditions on the "systems", so it does not hold in any system. And also: the first incompl. th. says nothing about true or false, but that there is a formula which is not provable nor is its negation.

Comment: Ah right. Yes I'm aware of the conditions and that the layman's terms that I use don't capture it exactly or in its entirety - but that's okay with me. Thank you very much - I think I'll use the version you gave!

Comment: Last question aphorisme: Is there a way to write it without the neither or nor do you think??

Comment: You could use $\neg \left( \textbf{PA} \vdash \phi  \right) \wedge \neg \left(\textbf{PA} \vdash \neg \phi \right)$

Comment: What does the symbol ⊢ mean?

Answer (score 53):

If you have enough skin and endurance, the following is not exactly Gödel's theorem, but an instance of a statement as predicted by Gödel's theorem, that is - with a suitable interpretation - it states that it is not provable (which means that it must be true, but unprovable - or PA is inconsistent). But don't complain if it turns out there is a typo buried inside ...

¬∃b:∃c:∃d:〈∃e:∃f:∃g:〈a=((((((e+ f)+ g)· ((e+ f)+ g))· ((e+ f)+ g))+ ((e+ f)· (e+ f)))+ e) ∧ ∃h:∃i:〈〈∃j:h=(j· Si) ∧ 〈∃j:h=(d+ (j· S(i· Sg))) ∧ ∃j:(d+ j)=(i· Sg)〉〉 ∧ ∀j:〈∃k:S(j+ k)=g ⇒ ∀k:∀l:〈〈〈∃m:h=(k+ (m· S(i· Sj))) ∧ ∃m:(k+ m)=(i· Sj)〉 ∧ 〈∃m:e=(l+ (m· S(f· Sj))) ∧ ∃m:(l+ m)=(f· Sj)〉〉 ⇒ 〈〈¬l=SSSSSSSSSS0 ⇒ 〈〈∃m:h=S(k+ (m· S(i· SSj))) ∧ ∃m:S(k+ m)=(i· SSj)〉 ∧ 〈∃m:b=(l+ (m· S(c· Sj))) ∧ ∃m:(l+ m)=(c· Sj)〉〉〉 ∧ 〈l=SSSSSSSSSS0 ⇒ 〈〈〈∃m:h=S((a+ k)+ (m· S(i· SSj))) ∧ ∃m:S((a+ k)+ m)=(i· SSj)〉 ∧ 〈∃m:b=SSSSSSSSS(m· S(c· S(a+ k))) ∧ ∃m:SSSSSSSSSm=(c· S(a+ k))〉〉 ∧ ∀m:〈∃n:S(m+ n)=a ⇒ 〈∃n:b=SSSSSSSS(n· S(c· S(m+ k))) ∧ ∃n:SSSSSSSSn=(c· S(m+ k))〉〉〉〉〉〉〉〉〉 ∧ ∃e:∃f:∃g:∃h:∃i:〈〈〈〈〈∃j:i=(j· Sf) ∧ ∃j:i=(j· S(f· Sg))〉 ∧ ∀j:∀k:∀l:〈〈〈∃m:S(j+ m)=g ∧ 〈∃m:i=(k+ (m· S(f· Sj))) ∧ ∃m:(k+ m)=(f· Sj)〉〉 ∧ 〈∃m:i=(l+ (m· S(f· SSj))) ∧ ∃m:(l+ m)=(f· SSj)〉〉 ⇒ 〈k=l ∨ 〈∃m:e=(m· S(f· Sj)) ∧ 〈k=Sl ∨ l=Sk〉〉〉〉〉 ∧ ∀j:〈∃k:S(j+ k)=g ⇒ ∀k:∀l:∀m:∀n:〈〈〈〈〈∃o:e=(k+ (o· S(f· Sj))) ∧ ∃o:(k+ o)=(f· Sj)〉 ∧ 〈∃o:h=(l+ (o· S(f· Sj))) ∧ ∃o:(l+ o)=(f· Sj)〉〉 ∧ 〈∃o:h=(m+ (o· S(f· SSj))) ∧ ∃o:(m+ o)=(f· SSj)〉〉 ∧ 〈∃o:h=(n+ (o· S(f· SS(m+ j)))) ∧ ∃o:(n+ o)=(f· SS(m+ j))〉〉 ⇒ 〈〈〈〈〈〈∃o:((j+ l)+ o)=g ∧ 〈∃o:SSSSSSSSSo=k ⇒ l=S0〉〉 ∧ 〈〈〈k=0 ∨ k=SSSSSSS0〉 ∨ k=SSSSSSSS0〉 ⇒ l=Sm〉〉 ∧ 〈〈〈〈〈〈k=S0 ∨ k=SS0〉 ∨ k=SSS0〉 ∨ k=SSSS0〉 ∨ k=SSSSS0〉 ∨ k=SSSSSS0〉 ⇒ 〈l=S(m+ n) ∧ ∀o:〈〈∃p:〈∃q:S(p+ q)=m ∧ 〈∃q:e=(o+ (q· S(f· SS(j+ p)))) ∧ ∃q:(o+ q)=(f· SS(j+ p))〉〉 ∧ ∃p:〈∃q:S(p+ q)=n ∧ 〈∃q:e=(o+ (q· S(f· SS((m+ j)+ p)))) ∧ ∃q:(o+ q)=(f· SS((m+ j)+ p))〉〉〉 ⇒ 〈〈∀p:¬〈〈∃q:S(p+ q)=m ∧ 〈∃q:e=SSSSSS(q· S(f· SS(j+ p))) ∧ ∃q:SSSSSSq=(f· SS(j+ p))〉〉 ∧ 〈∃q:e=(o+ (q· S(f· SSS(j+ p)))) ∧ ∃q:(o+ q)=(f· SSS(j+ p))〉〉 ∨ ∀p:¬〈〈∃q:S(p+ q)=n ∧ 〈∃q:e=SSSSSS(q· S(f· SS((m+ j)+ p))) ∧ ∃q:SSSSSSq=(f· SS((m+ j)+ p))〉〉 ∧ 〈∃q:e=(o+ (q· S(f· SSS((m+ j)+ p)))) ∧ ∃q:(o+ q)=(f· SSS((m+ j)+ p))〉〉〉 ⇒ ∀p:¬〈〈∃q:S(p+ q)=(m+ n) ∧ 〈∃q:e=SSSSSS(q· S(f· SS(j+ p))) ∧ ∃q:SSSSSSq=(f· SS(j+ p))〉〉 ∧ 〈∃q:e=(o+ (q· S(f· SSS(j+ p)))) ∧ ∃q:(o+ q)=(f· SSS(j+ p))〉〉〉〉〉〉〉 ∧ ∀o:〈〈∃p:e=(o+ (p· S(f· SSj))) ∧ ∃p:(o+ p)=(f· SSj)〉 ⇒ 〈〈〈〈〈〈k=0 ∨ k=S0〉 ∨ k=SS0〉 ∨ k=SSSSSSS0〉 ⇒ 〈〈〈〈o=S0 ∨ o=SS0〉 ∨ o=SSS0〉 ∨ o=SSSSSS0〉 ∨ o=SSSSSSS0〉〉 ∧ 〈〈〈〈k=SSS0 ∨ k=SSSS0〉 ∨ k=SSSSS0〉 ∨ k=SSSSSSSS0〉 ⇒ 〈〈o=SSSS0 ∨ o=SSSSS0〉 ∨ ∃p:SSSSSSSSp=o〉〉〉 ∧ 〈k=SSSSSS0 ⇒ ∃p:SSSSSSSSSSp=o〉〉〉〉 ∧ ∀o:〈〈∃p:e=(o+ (p· S(f· SS(m+ j)))) ∧ ∃p:(o+ p)=(f· SS(m+ j))〉 ⇒ 〈〈〈k=0 ⇒ k=o〉 ∧ 〈〈〈k=S0 ∨ k=SS0〉 ∨ k=SSSSSS0〉 ⇒ 〈〈〈〈o=S0 ∨ o=SS0〉 ∨ o=SSS0〉 ∨ o=SSSSSS0〉 ∨ o=SSSSSSS0〉〉〉 ∧ 〈〈〈k=SSS0 ∨ k=SSSS0〉 ∨ k=SSSSS0〉 ⇒ 〈〈o=SSSS0 ∨ o=SSSSS0〉 ∨ ∃p:SSSSSSSSp=o〉〉〉〉〉 ∧ 〈j=0 ⇒ k=0〉〉〉〉〉 ∧ ∃j:〈〈〈g=S(j+ d) ∧ ∃k:e=(k· S(f· Sj))〉 ∧ ∀k:¬〈〈∃l:S(k+ l)=d ∧ 〈∃l:b=SSSSSS(l· S(c· Sk)) ∧ ∃l:SSSSSSl=(c· Sk)〉〉 ∧ ∃l:b=(l· S(c· SSk))〉〉 ∧ ∀k:∀l:〈〈∃m:S(k+ m)=d ∧ 〈∃m:b=(l+ (m· S(c· Sk))) ∧ ∃m:(l+ m)=(c· Sk)〉〉 ⇒ 〈∃m:e=(l+ (m· S(f· SS(j+ k)))) ∧ ∃m:(l+ m)=(f· SS(j+ k))〉〉〉〉 ∧ ∀j:∀k:〈〈∃l:e=(l· S(f· Sj)) ∧ 〈∃l:h=(k+ (l· S(f· SSj))) ∧ ∃l:(k+ l)=(f· SSj)〉〉 ⇒ 〈〈〈〈∃l:e=SSSSSS(l· S(f· SSj)) ∧ ∃l:SSSSSSl=(f· SSj)〉 ∧ 〈∃l:e=SSSSSSSSSS(l· S(f· SSSj)) ∧ ∃l:SSSSSSSSSSl=(f· SSSj)〉〉 ∧ 〈〈〈〈〈〈∃l:e=SSSSSSS(l· S(f· SSSSj)) ∧ ∃l:e=SSS(l· S(f· SSSSSj))〉 ∧ ∃l:e=SSSSSSSS(l· S(f· SSSSSSj))〉 ∧ ∃l:e=SSSSSSSSSS(l· S(f· SSSSSSSj))〉 ∧ ∃l:e=SSSSSSSSS(l· S(f· SSSSSSSSj))〉 ∨ 〈〈〈∃l:e=SSS(l· S(f· SSSSj)) ∧ ∃l:e=SSSSSSSSSS(l· S(f· SSSSSSj))〉 ∧ ∃l:e=SSSSSSSSS(l· S(f· SSSSSSSj))〉 ∧ 〈〈∃l:e=SSSS(l· S(f· SSSSSj)) ∧ ∃l:e=SSSSSSSSSS(l· S(f· SSSSSSSSj))〉 ∨ 〈∃l:e=SSSSS(l· S(f· SSSSSj)) ∧ ∃l:e=SSSSSSSSS(l· S(f· SSSSSSSSj))〉〉〉〉 ∨ 〈〈〈〈〈〈〈〈∃l:e=SSSSSS(l· S(f· SSSSj)) ∧ ∃l:e=SSSSSSSSSSS(l· S(f· SSSSSj))〉 ∧ ∃l:e=SSS(l· S(f· SSSSSSj))〉 ∧ ∃l:e=SSSSSSSSSS(l· S(f· SSSSSSSSj))〉 ∧ ∃l:e=SSSSSSSS(l· S(f· SSSSSSSSSj))〉 ∧ ∃l:e=SSSSSSSSSSS(l· S(f· SSSSSSSSSSj))〉 ∧ ∃l:e=SSSSSSSSSS(l· S(f· SSSSSSSSSSSSSj))〉 ∧ ∃l:e=SSSSSSSSSSS(l· S(f· SSSSSSSSSSSSSSj))〉 ∧ 〈〈〈∃l:e=SSSS(l· S(f· SSSSSSSj)) ∧ ∃l:e=SSSSSSSS(l· S(f· SSSSSSSSSSSj))〉 ∧ ∃l:e=SSSS(l· S(f· SSSSSSSSSSSSj))〉 ∨ 〈〈〈∃l:e=SSSSS(l· S(f· SSSSSSSj)) ∧ ∃l:e=SSSS(l· S(f· SSSSSSSSSSSj))〉 ∧ 〈∃l:e=SSSSS(l· S(f· SSSSSSSSSSSSj)) ∧ ∃l:SSSSSl=(f· SSSSSSSSSSSSj)〉〉 ∧ ∃l:e=SSSSSSSSSS(l· S(f· SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSj))〉〉〉〉〉 ∨ ∃l:∃m:〈〈〈〈∃n:S(l+ n)=j ∧ ∃n:e=(n· S(f· Sl))〉 ∧ 〈∃n:h=(m+ (n· S(f· SSl))) ∧ ∃n:(m+ n)=(f· SSl)〉〉 ∧ ∀n:∀o:∀p:〈〈〈〈∃q:i=(n+ (q· S(f· SSl))) ∧ ∃q:(n+ q)=(f· SSl)〉 ∧ ∃q:((l+ o)+ q)=j〉 ∧ 〈∃q:i=(p+ (q· S(f· SS(l+ o)))) ∧ ∃q:(p+ q)=(f· SS(l+ o))〉〉 ⇒ ∃q:(p+ q)=n〉〉 ∧ 〈〈〈〈〈〈〈〈〈〈〈∀n:∀o:〈〈∃p:S(n+ p)=m ∧ 〈∃p:e=(o+ (p· S(f· SS(n+ j)))) ∧ ∃p:(o+ p)=(f· SS(n+ j))〉〉 ⇒ ∃p:e=(o+ (p· S(f· SS(n+ l))))〉 ∨ 〈〈〈∃n:e=SSS(n· S(f· SSj)) ∧ ∃n:SSSn=(f· SSj)〉 ∧ k=m〉 ∧ ∃n:∃o:〈〈S(n+ o)=k ∧ ∀p:∀q:〈〈∃r:S(p+ r)=o ∧ 〈∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SSS(p+ j)))) ∧ ∃r:(q+ r)=(f· SSS(p+ j))〉〉 ⇒ ∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SSS(p+ (l+ n)))))〉〉 ∧ ∀p:∀q:〈〈∃r:S(p+ r)=n ∧ 〈∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SSS(p+ (j+ o))))) ∧ ∃r:(q+ r)=(f· SSS(p+ (j+ o)))〉〉 ⇒ ∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SSS(p+ l))))〉〉〉〉 ∨ 〈〈〈∃n:e=SSSSSSS(n· S(f· SSj)) ∧ ∃n:SSSSSSSn=(f· SSj)〉 ∧ k=SSm〉 ∧ ∀n:∀o:〈〈∃p:S(n+ p)=m ∧ 〈∃p:e=(o+ (p· S(f· SSSS(n+ j)))) ∧ ∃p:(o+ p)=(f· SSSS(n+ j))〉〉 ⇒ 〈∃p:e=(o+ (p· S(f· SS(n+ l)))) ∧ ∃p:(o+ p)=(f· SS(n+ l))〉〉〉〉 ∨ 〈〈〈∃n:e=SSSSSSS(n· S(f· SSl)) ∧ ∃n:SSSSSSSn=(f· SSl)〉 ∧ m=SSk〉 ∧ ∀n:∀o:〈〈∃p:S(n+ p)=k ∧ 〈∃p:e=(o+ (p· S(f· SSSS(n+ l)))) ∧ ∃p:(o+ p)=(f· SSSS(n+ l))〉〉 ⇒ 〈∃p:e=(o+ (p· S(f· SS(n+ j)))) ∧ ∃p:(o+ p)=(f· SS(n+ j))〉〉〉〉 ∨ ∃n:∃o:〈〈〈〈〈〈∃p:h=(n+ (p· S(f· SSSl))) ∧ ∃p:(n+ p)=(f· SSSl)〉 ∧ S(n+ o)=m〉 ∧ 〈∃p:e=SSSSSSSS(p· S(f· SSSj)) ∧ ∃p:SSSSSSSSp=(f· SSSj)〉〉 ∧ 〈∃p:e=SSSSSSSS(p· S(f· SSSS(j+ n))) ∧ ∃p:SSSSSSSSp=(f· SSSS(j+ n))〉〉 ∧ ∀p:∀q:〈〈∃r:S(p+ r)=n ∧ 〈∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SSSS(p+ j)))) ∧ ∃r:(q+ r)=(f· SSSS(p+ j))〉〉 ⇒ 〈∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SSS(p+ l)))) ∧ ∃r:(q+ r)=(f· SSS(p+ l))〉〉〉 ∧ ∀p:∀q:〈〈∃r:S(p+ r)=o ∧ 〈∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SSSSS(p+ (j+ n))))) ∧ ∃r:(q+ r)=(f· SSSSS(p+ (j+ n)))〉〉 ⇒ 〈∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SSS(p+ (l+ n))))) ∧ ∃r:(q+ r)=(f· SSS(p+ (l+ n)))〉〉〉〉 ∨ ∃n:∃o:〈〈〈〈〈〈∃p:h=(n+ (p· S(f· SSSj))) ∧ ∃p:(n+ p)=(f· SSSj)〉 ∧ S(n+ o)=k〉 ∧ 〈∃p:e=SSSSSSSS(p· S(f· SSSl)) ∧ ∃p:SSSSSSSSp=(f· SSSl)〉〉 ∧ 〈∃p:e=SSSSSSSS(p· S(f· SSSS(l+ n))) ∧ ∃p:SSSSSSSSp=(f· SSSS(l+ n))〉〉 ∧ ∀p:∀q:〈〈∃r:S(p+ r)=n ∧ 〈∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SSSS(p+ l)))) ∧ ∃r:(q+ r)=(f· SSSS(p+ l))〉〉 ⇒ 〈∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SSS(p+ j)))) ∧ ∃r:(q+ r)=(f· SSS(p+ j))〉〉〉 ∧ ∀p:∀q:〈〈∃r:S(p+ r)=o ∧ 〈∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SSSSS(p+ (l+ n))))) ∧ ∃r:(q+ r)=(f· SSSSS(p+ (l+ n)))〉〉 ⇒ 〈∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SSS(p+ (j+ n))))) ∧ ∃r:(q+ r)=(f· SSS(p+ (j+ n)))〉〉〉〉 ∨ 〈〈∃n:e=SS(n· S(f· SSl)) ∧ ∃n:SSn=(f· SSl)〉 ∧ ∀n:∀o:〈〈∃p:S(n+ p)=k ∧ 〈∃p:e=(o+ (p· S(f· SS(n+ j)))) ∧ ∃p:(o+ p)=(f· SS(n+ j))〉〉 ⇒ ∃p:e=(o+ (p· S(f· SSS(n+ l))))〉〉〉 ∨ ∃n:〈〈〈∃o:h=(n+ (o· S(f· SSSl))) ∧ ∃o:(n+ o)=(f· SSSl)〉 ∧ 〈∃o:e=SS(o· S(f· SSl)) ∧ ∃o:SSo=(f· SSl)〉〉 ∧ ∀o:∀p:〈〈∃q:S(o+ q)=k ∧ 〈∃q:e=(p+ (q· S(f· SS(o+ j)))) ∧ ∃q:(p+ q)=(f· SS(o+ j))〉〉 ⇒ ∃q:e=(p+ (q· S(f· SSS(o+ (l+ n)))))〉〉〉 ∨ 〈k=SSm ∧ ∃n:∃o:〈〈〈〈S(n+ o)=m ∧ 〈∃p:e=S(p· S(f· SSj)) ∧ ∃p:Sp=(f· SSj)〉〉 ∧ 〈∃p:e=S(p· S(f· SSl)) ∧ ∃p:Sp=(f· SSl)〉〉 ∧ ∀p:∀q:〈〈∃r:S(p+ r)=o ∧ 〈∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SSSSS(p+ (j+ n))))) ∧ ∃r:(q+ r)=(f· SSSSS(p+ (j+ n)))〉〉 ⇒ ∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SSS(p+ l))))〉〉 ∧ ∀p:∀q:〈〈∃r:S(p+ r)=n ∧ 〈∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SSSS(p+ j)))) ∧ ∃r:(q+ r)=(f· SSSS(p+ j))〉〉 ⇒ ∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SSS(p+ (l+ o)))))〉〉〉〉 ∨ ∃n:∃o:∃p:∃q:〈〈〈m=SSq ∧ 〈∃r:e=SSSSSS(r· S(f· SSl)) ∧ ∃r:SSSSSSr=(f· SSl)〉〉 ∧ 〈∃r:e=(n+ (r· S(f· SSSl))) ∧ ∃r:(n+ r)=(f· SSSl)〉〉 ∧ 〈∀r:〈∃s:〈∃t:S(s+ t)=p ∧ 〈∃t:e=(r+ (t· S(f· S(o+ s)))) ∧ ∃t:(r+ t)=(f· S(o+ s))〉〉 ⇒ ∀s:¬〈〈∃t:S(s+ t)=q ∧ 〈∃t:e=SSSSSS(t· S(f· SSSS(l+ s))) ∧ ∃t:SSSSSSt=(f· SSSS(l+ s))〉〉 ∧ 〈∃t:e=(r+ (t· S(f· SSSSS(l+ s)))) ∧ ∃t:(r+ t)=(f· SSSSS(l+ s))〉〉〉 ∧ ∃r:∃s:〈〈∃t:r=(t· Ss) ∧ 〈∃t:r=(k+ (t· S(s· Sq))) ∧ ∃t:(k+ t)=(s· Sq)〉〉 ∧ ∀t:∀u:∀v:∀w:〈〈〈〈∃x:S(t+ x)=q ∧ 〈∃x:r=(u+ (x· S(s· St))) ∧ ∃x:(u+ x)=(s· St)〉〉 ∧ 〈∃x:r=(v+ (x· S(s· SSt))) ∧ ∃x:(v+ x)=(s· SSt)〉〉 ∧ 〈∃x:e=(w+ (x· S(f· SSSS(l+ t)))) ∧ ∃x:(w+ x)=(f· SSSS(l+ t))〉〉 ⇒ 〈〈¬w=n ⇒ 〈〈∃x:e=(w+ (x· S(f· SS(j+ u)))) ∧ ∃x:(w+ x)=(f· SS(j+ u))〉 ∧ v=Su〉〉 ∧ 〈w=n ⇒ 〈∀x:∀y:〈〈∃z:S(x+ z)=p ∧ 〈∃z:e=(y+ (z· S(f· S(o+ x)))) ∧ ∃z:(y+ z)=(f· S(o+ x))〉〉 ⇒ 〈∃z:e=(y+ (z· S(f· SS((x+ u)+ j)))) ∧ ∃z:(y+ z)=(f· SS((x+ u)+ j))〉〉 ∧ v=(p+ u)〉〉〉〉〉〉〉〉 ∨ ∃n:〈∀o:〈〈〈∃p:S(o+ p)=j ∧ ∃p:e=(p· S(f· So))〉 ∧ ∀p:∀q:∀r:〈〈〈〈∃s:i=(q+ (s· S(f· So))) ∧ ∃s:(q+ s)=(f· So)〉 ∧ 〈∃s:i=(r+ (s· S(f· SS(p+ o)))) ∧ ∃s:(r+ s)=(f· SS(p+ o))〉〉 ∧ ∃s:S((o+ p)+ s)=j〉 ⇒ ∃s:S(q+ s)=r〉〉 ⇒ ∀p:¬〈〈〈∃q:h=(p+ (q· S(f· So))) ∧ ∃q:(p+ q)=(f· So)〉 ∧ ∃q:〈∃r:S(q+ r)=p ∧ 〈∃r:e=(n+ (r· S(f· S(o+ q)))) ∧ ∃r:(n+ r)=(f· S(o+ q))〉〉〉 ∧ ∀q:¬〈〈∃r:S(q+ r)=p ∧ 〈∃r:e=SSSSSS(r· S(f· S(o+ q))) ∧ ∃r:SSSSSSr=(f· S(o+ q))〉〉 ∧ 〈∃r:e=(n+ (r· S(f· SS(o+ q)))) ∧ ∃r:(n+ r)=(f· SS(o+ q))〉〉〉〉 ∧ 〈〈〈∃o:e=SSSSSS(o· S(f· SSj)) ∧ ∃o:SSSSSSo=(f· SSj)〉 ∧ 〈∃o:e=(n+ (o· S(f· SSSj))) ∧ ∃o:(n+ o)=(f· SSSj)〉〉 ∧ ∀o:∀p:〈〈∃q:S(o+ q)=m ∧ 〈∃q:e=(p+ (q· S(f· SSSS(o+ j)))) ∧ ∃q:(p+ q)=(f· SSSS(o+ j))〉〉 ⇒ 〈∃q:e=(p+ (q· S(f· SS(o+ l)))) ∧ ∃q:(p+ q)=(f· SS(o+ l))〉〉〉〉〉 ∨ ∃n:∃o:〈〈〈〈∃p:S(n+ p)=j ∧ ∃p:e=(p· S(f· Sn))〉 ∧ 〈∃p:h=(o+ (p· S(f· SSn))) ∧ ∃p:(o+ p)=(f· SSn)〉〉 ∧ ∀p:∀q:∀r:〈〈〈〈∃s:i=(p+ (s· S(f· SSn))) ∧ ∃s:(p+ s)=(f· SSn)〉 ∧ ∃s:((n+ q)+ s)=j〉 ∧ 〈∃s:i=(r+ (s· S(f· SS(n+ q)))) ∧ ∃s:(r+ s)=(f· SS(n+ q))〉〉 ⇒ ∃s:(r+ s)=p〉〉 ∧ 〈〈〈〈〈〈〈∃p:e=SS(p· S(f· SSj)) ∧ ∃p:SSp=(f· SSj)〉 ∧ ∀p:∀q:〈〈∃r:S(p+ r)=m ∧ 〈∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SSS(p+ j)))) ∧ ∃r:(q+ r)=(f· SSS(p+ j))〉〉 ⇒ ∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SS(p+ l))))〉〉 ∧ ∀p:∀q:〈〈∃r:S(p+ r)=o ∧ 〈∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SSS(p+ (j+ m))))) ∧ ∃r:(q+ r)=(f· SSS(p+ (j+ m)))〉〉 ⇒ ∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SS(p+ n))))〉〉 ∨ 〈〈〈∃p:e=S(p· S(f· SSl)) ∧ ∃p:Sp=(f· SSl)〉 ∧ ∀p:∀q:〈〈∃r:S(p+ r)=o ∧ 〈∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SSS(p+ l)))) ∧ ∃r:(q+ r)=(f· SSS(p+ l))〉〉 ⇒ 〈∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SS(p+ n)))) ∧ ∃r:(q+ r)=(f· SS(p+ n))〉〉〉 ∧ ∀p:∀q:〈〈∃r:S(p+ r)=k ∧ 〈∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SS(p+ j)))) ∧ ∃r:(q+ r)=(f· SS(p+ j))〉〉 ⇒ 〈∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SSS(p+ (l+ o))))) ∧ ∃r:(q+ r)=(f· SSS(p+ (l+ o)))〉〉〉〉 ∨ 〈〈∃p:e=SSS(p· S(f· SSj)) ∧ ∃p:SSSp=(f· SSj)〉 ∧ ∃p:∃q:∃r:〈〈〈〈〈S(p+ q)=k ∧ S(p+ r)=m〉 ∧ S(r+ q)=o〉 ∧ ∀s:∀t:〈〈∃u:S(s+ u)=p ∧ 〈∃u:e=(t+ (u· S(f· SSS(s+ j)))) ∧ ∃u:(t+ u)=(f· SSS(s+ j))〉〉 ⇒ ∃u:e=(t+ (u· S(f· SSS(s+ l))))〉〉 ∧ ∀s:∀t:〈〈∃u:S(s+ u)=r ∧ 〈∃u:e=(t+ (u· S(f· SSS(s+ n)))) ∧ ∃u:(t+ u)=(f· SSS(s+ n))〉〉 ⇒ 〈∃u:e=(t+ (u· S(f· SSS(s+ (l+ p))))) ∧ ∃u:(t+ u)=(f· SSS(s+ (l+ p)))〉〉〉 ∧ ∀s:∀t:〈〈∃u:S(s+ u)=q ∧ 〈∃u:e=(t+ (u· S(f· SSS(s+ (j+ p))))) ∧ ∃u:(t+ u)=(f· SSS(s+ (j+ p)))〉〉 ⇒ ∃u:e=(t+ (u· S(f· SSS(s+ (n+ r)))))〉〉〉〉 ∨ ∃p:〈〈〈〈〈〈〈〈∃q:e=SSSSSS(q· S(f· SSj)) ∧ ∃q:SSSSSSq=(f· SSj)〉 ∧ 〈∃q:e=(p+ (q· S(f· SSSj))) ∧ ∃q:(p+ q)=(f· SSSj)〉〉 ∧ 〈∃q:e=SSSSSS(q· S(f· SSn)) ∧ ∃q:SSSSSSq=(f· SSn)〉〉 ∧ 〈∃q:e=(p+ (q· S(f· SSSn))) ∧ ∃q:(p+ q)=(f· SSSn)〉〉 ∧ 〈∃q:e=S(q· S(f· SSSSn)) ∧ ∃q:Sq=(f· SSSSn)〉〉 ∧ ∀q:∀r:〈〈∃s:S(q+ s)=m ∧ 〈∃s:e=(r+ (s· S(f· SSSS(q+ j)))) ∧ ∃s:(r+ s)=(f· SSSS(q+ j))〉〉 ⇒ 〈∃s:e=(r+ (s· S(f· SSSSS(q+ n)))) ∧ ∃s:(r+ s)=(f· SSSSS(q+ n))〉〉〉 ∧ ∀q:∀r:∀s:〈〈〈∃t:S(q+ t)=m ∧ 〈∃t:e=(r+ (t· S(f· SS(l+ q)))) ∧ ∃t:(r+ t)=(f· SS(l+ q))〉〉 ∧ 〈∃t:e=(s+ (t· S(f· SSSS(j+ q)))) ∧ ∃t:(s+ t)=(f· SSSS(j+ q))〉〉 ⇒ 〈〈s=p ⇒ r=SSSSSSSSS0〉 ∧ 〈¬s=p ⇒ r=s〉〉〉〉 ∧ ∃q:∃r:〈〈∃s:q=SSSS((m+ l)+ (s· S(r· SSSSj))) ∧ ∃s:SSSS((m+ l)+ s)=(r· SSSSj)〉 ∧ ∀s:∀t:∀u:∀v:∀w:〈〈〈〈〈∃x:S(s+ x)=m ∧ 〈∃x:q=(t+ (x· S(r· SSSS(j+ s)))) ∧ ∃x:(t+ x)=(r· SSSS(j+ s))〉〉 ∧ 〈∃x:q=(u+ (x· S(r· SSSSS(j+ s)))) ∧ ∃x:(u+ x)=(r· SSSSS(j+ s))〉〉 ∧ 〈∃x:e=(v+ (x· S(f· SSSS(j+ s)))) ∧ ∃x:(v+ x)=(f· SSSS(j+ s))〉〉 ∧ 〈∃x:e=(w+ (x· S(f· St))) ∧ ∃x:(w+ x)=(f· St)〉〉 ⇒ 〈〈v=p ⇒ 〈〈u=SSt ∧ 〈∃x:e=(p+ (x· S(f· SSt))) ∧ ∃x:(p+ x)=(f· SSt)〉〉 ∧ w=SSSSSSSS0〉〉 ∧ 〈¬v=p ⇒ 〈u=St ∧ w=v〉〉〉〉〉〉〉 ∨ 〈∃p:〈〈〈S(n+ o)=j ∧ 〈∃q:i=(p+ (q· S(f· Sl))) ∧ ∃q:(p+ q)=(f· Sl)〉〉 ∧ 〈∃q:i=(p+ (q· S(f· SSj))) ∧ ∃q:(p+ q)=(f· SSj)〉〉 ∧ ∀q:∀r:〈〈∃s:S((l+ q)+ s)=j ∧ 〈∃s:i=(r+ (s· S(f· SS(l+ q)))) ∧ ∃s:(r+ s)=(f· SS(l+ q))〉〉 ⇒ ∃s:S(p+ s)=r〉〉 ∧ 〈〈〈∃p:e=S(p· S(f· SSj)) ∧ ∃p:Sp=(f· SSj)〉 ∧ ∀p:∀q:〈〈∃r:S(p+ r)=m ∧ 〈∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SSS(p+ j)))) ∧ ∃r:(q+ r)=(f· SSS(p+ j))〉〉 ⇒ 〈∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SS(p+ l)))) ∧ ∃r:(q+ r)=(f· SS(p+ l))〉〉〉 ∧ ∀p:∀q:〈〈∃r:S(p+ r)=o ∧ 〈∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SS(p+ n)))) ∧ ∃r:(q+ r)=(f· SS(p+ n))〉〉 ⇒ 〈∃r:e=(q+ (r· S(f· SSS(p+ (j+ m))))) ∧ ∃r:(q+ r)=(f· SSS(p+ (j+ m)))〉〉〉〉〉〉〉〉〉〉〉〉

Comment: What is the statement, and how did you generate this thing?

Comment: Best possible answer!

Comment: Ha! Amazing. Funnily enough I am not looking to cover my entire body. But this is awesome.

Comment: @Spenser I generated it years ago in an attempt to make Hofstadters *Gödel, Escher, Bach* more "explicit". It follows the "recipe" as given there, including the precise formulation of axioms and rules of inference, and uses the Chinese Remainder Theorem to encode arbitrarily long sequences of naturals as three naturals. Also "b is a power of 10": ∃n:∃a:∃c:∃d:∃e: ∀p:∀q:∀r:∀s:∀t: ∃f:∃g: 〈〈S(a· SSc)=(b+ (d· S(Sc· Sn))) ∧ (b+ e)=(Sc· Sn)〉 ∧ 〈〈〈¬S(p+ r)=n ∨ ¬S(a· SSc)=(q+ (s· S(Sc· Sp)))〉 ∨ ¬(q+ t)=(Sc· Sp) 〉 ∨ 〈S(a· SSc)=((SSSSSSSSSS0· q)+ (f· S(Sc· SSp))) ∧ ((SSSSSSSSSS0· q)+ g)=(Sc· SSp)〉〉〉

Comment: I love that you have this just sitting around, waiting for an application.

Comment: What is the encoding of this formula? It's full of squares in my browser (Chrome).

Comment: @MackTuesday:  as far as I can tell they are all angle brackets.  It is an exercise for the reader to figure out which direction each represents.  I opened it in Firefox and it comes out fine.

Comment: FWIW it's fine in my Chome, on a Mac.

Comment: This can be simplified. I see parts that say `∨ o=SSSS0` (with varying numbers of occurrences of `S`). I'm assuming `S` is the successor function, in which case `o=SSSS0` reduces to `0=4`, or false.

Comment: @DavidKnipe I guess 'o' is just a variable, not necessarily zero.

Answer (score 9):

Gödel's second incompleteness theorem has a succinct description:

$$ PA \not{\vdash} Con(PA). $$

Comment: Ooh, Very nice. Thanks. I'm actually after the meaning of the first one. After posting this an explanation came up on this site actually. Do you think this could be used for the first one? F⊢GF↔¬ProvF(⌜GF⌝).

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/839731/g%C3%B6del-incompleteness-theorem

Answer (score 5):

You could look at [Raymond Smullyan's Godel's Incompleteness Theorems](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0195046722) . It gives the development. I don't remember it being so expensive when I bought it, and my bookshelf is now inaccessible.

Comment: Thanks. Might try to find a way to peek at one for free. Pricey!